# Vertical position of a list changes in beamer

Tags: beamer, itemize, minipage

Why does the list move upwards when last item appears?

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]{foo}

\begin{minipage}[c]{.5\linewidth}
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
\item Começamos com \alert{$p=2$} e marcamos todos os seus múltiplos $(\textcolor{blue}{4, 6, 8, \dots} )$. 

\item Tomamos o próximo número não marcado (\alert{$p=3$}) e marcamos todos os seus múltiplos não marcados $(\textcolor{green!60!black}{9, 15, 21, \dots})$.

\item Analogamente para \alert{$p=5$}.

\item Por fim, para \alert{$p=7$}.

\end{itemize}%
\end{minipage}\quad%
\begin{minipage}[c]{.45\linewidth}
\only<1>{\includegraphics[height=.85\textheight,width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}}
\only<2>{\includegraphics[height=.85\textheight,width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}}
\only<3>{\includegraphics[height=.85\textheight,width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}}
\only<4>{\includegraphics[height=.85\textheight,width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}}
\end{minipage}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The missing `%` at the end of lines act like spaces. Depending on which overlay you are on, they are either before or after the image. If there are too many spaces after the image, this will cause an additional line to be added.

Here a visualisation with a `\fbox` around the minipage to show its size:

[image]

If you add the `%`s, the list stops jumping:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]{foo}

\begin{minipage}[c]{.5\linewidth}
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
\item Começamos com \alert{$p=2$} e marcamos todos os seus múltiplos $(\textcolor{blue}{4, 6, 8, \dots} )$. 

\item Tomamos o próximo número não marcado (\alert{$p=3$}) e marcamos todos os seus múltiplos não marcados $(\textcolor{green!60!black}{9, 15, 21, \dots})$.

\item Analogamente para \alert{$p=5$}.

\item Por fim, para \alert{$p=7$}.

\end{itemize}%
\end{minipage}\quad%
\begin{minipage}[c]{.45\linewidth}
\only<1>{\includegraphics[height=.85\textheight,width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}}%
\only<2>{\includegraphics[height=.85\textheight,width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}}%
\only<3>{\includegraphics[height=.85\textheight,width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}}%
\only<4>{\includegraphics[height=.85\textheight,width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}}%
\end{minipage}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ohhhh, how could I forget that?! Thanks.

Comment: @Sigur You're welcome!

Comment: But it is strange to me, since the images are inside the right minipage. So, in some sense, the empty spaces change that minipage size?

Comment: @Sigur Basically yes. Depending on how many spaces are after the images, their combined width gets too wide which will add a new line at the end of the minipage

Comment: @Sigur See this version with an fbox around the minipage: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbPhK.gif

Comment: The fbox was useful. It is clear now the extra line. Very interesting.